# Django Admin: Dynamically remove inline fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to dynamically remove an inline if the user doesn't have the specified permission to edit that data. However, the inline only shows up when I'm logged in as a super user. How would I fix this? I'm using the [django-nested-inline package.](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) Currently I'm doing:

```
class ClientAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    """
    Admin for Clients. adp_id is only editable if the user has the permission.
    """
    fieldsets = [
    (None, {'fields': [('user', 'company', 'external_id',)]}),
    ]
    inlines = [EventInline]

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Removes the EventInline if user doesn't have the edit_event permission.
        """
        if not request.user.has_perm('app.edit_event'):
            self.inlines = []
        return super(ClientAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)


class EventInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Event
    fk_name = 'client'
    ordering = ['completion_time']
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': [('training', 'status', 'due_date'), ('authorized_by', 'completion_time'), 'comments']})
    ]
    extra = 0
```

I want to remove the `EventInline` from `inlines` or make all the fields in the `EventInline` read only. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't showing up because the user didn't have the permission to add/edit/delete the nested inline Event. Just in case anybody has this problem in the future I'll leave it up.

```
app | event | Can add event
app | event | Can change event
app | event | Can delete event
```